# GAE: How to access a property value from within @classmethod

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

How can we access a property value within a `@classmethod`? For example:

```
class Account(polymodel.PolyModel):
  someprop = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
​
    @classmethod
    def get_or_create_someprop(cls):
        if not cls.someprop:
            # create someprop
        else: 
            return cls.someprop
```

In this example code above, I am trying create `someprop` if it doesn’t exist, or return it if it already exists. I assumed that the above code would achieve this. However, the first step I need to do is access the `someprop` value from within the classmethod. Using `cls.someprop` does not actually return the value of `someprop` but instead returns `StringProperty('state')`.

I have tried to use `this` and `self` which are `undefined`.

So, is it possible to access a property value of an entity using a classmethod? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot do this from a class method because a property belongs to an object, i.e. an instance of the class (the class is just the object generator). In other words you need the `self` argument to refer to the object and its properties.

In your particular case the class is an entity model (the blueprint for creating entities), not an entity and you can only refer to a property of an entity itself.

But you *should* be able to achieve what you seek simply by not declaring it a class method - then it becomes a method of the object/entity and in that case you can reference the entity's property via `self` instead of `cls`: `self.someprop`.

I'd make the check a bit more specific, though, to cover the case in which the property has a value like 0 or an empty string which is interpreted by python as `False` in a logical check: `if self.someprop is None` instead of `if not self.someprop`.